# How do I conditionally format based on the value of cells in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Unable to create a script. I would like to know if there is one that would allow me to color an entire row based on the value (a different color value) that I will find in the cells of column B.

For example, I want to color all rows that have the same value in the column B with the same color. For example If I have X in cell B2, B6, B8 The rows 1,6 and 8 in blue, if I have Y in B1, B5, B7 The rows 1,5,7 must be in green, etc.  Only 10 possibilities with the conditional formatting, it's not enough for me.

Comment: You need to put in more effort in posting a question, JG. As it stands, it's not clear what you want. Read up in our [help] to know more [about] that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "on change call setRowColour()" trigger in the script editor (Resources>Current Project's Triggers) and add this in code.gs:

```
function setRowColour() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

    // Get the colour of B2.   
    var colour = sheet.getRange('B2').getBackground();

    // Set the colour of row A.   
    var maxColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,maxColumn);
    range.setBackground(colour);    
}
```

I've made an example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhRtIprIrwuzdEdXeXdGdTRRYlk3Z2xfSFREWlA3Q1E&usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you very much but it's not quite what I want. Color all rows that have the same value in column B. Is this accurate?

Comment: This dynamically sets the background colour of row A to the background colour of cell B2. Could you describe exactly what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to color all rows that have the same value in the column B with the same color. For example If I have X in cell B2, B6, B8 The rows 1,6 et 8 in Blue, if I have Y in B1, B5, B7 The rows 1,5,7 must be in green etc..Only 10 possibilities with the conditionnal formating, it's not enough for me. JJ.